# Does Chrome Custom Tabs allow sites to change the titlebar color?

Tags: chrome-custom-tabs

Will Chrome Custom Tabs allow websites to change the titlebar color with <meta name=theme-color />?

Answer (score 2):

No, Chrome Custom Tabs does not honor theme-color meta tags or allow websites to modify the title bar in the any of the ways that Chrome does.